# SQL query optimization Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I have this SQL query that first selects from a relative short table a number that is used after for another select, this time from a very large table, certain info using the code from the first one. This takes more than 30 minutes for only one select and i need to optimize as i have to run 300 selects like this one but with different SWNAMEs. I would appreciate any hints and tips that you can give me. Thank you !

```
SELECT SWOBJECTID 
FROM   MBR_INST_PRODUCTS 
WHERE  SWPRODRELEASEID IN 
       (SELECT SWPRODRELEASEID 
        FROM   ORO_PPY_OPTIONS 
        WHERE  SWNAME LIKE 'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON')
AND rownum <2;
```

Comment: Why `like` and  why not `SWNAME =  'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON'`?

Comment: `SWNAME 
    like 'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON'` is exactly the same thing as `SWNAME = 'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON'`

Comment: `Over 300 of these queries in a run` - could you please edit your question to add more details about what a run consists of? For example, it's possible that you don't need 300 queries (maybe a single query could do the work), so tuning each individual query might not be the correct way to go. Also, what does "an awful lot of time" mean? What indexes are present on both tables? What's the execution plan? Please update your question to add in these extra details, to help us to be able to help you better.

Comment: I edited the question and put the indexes and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple join?

```
SELECT m.swobjectid
  FROM mbr_inst_products m
       JOIN oro_ppy_options o ON o.swprodreleaseid = m.swprodreleaseid
 WHERE     o.swname = 'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON'
       AND ROWNUM < 2;
```

Make sure `swprodreleaseid` columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this query as:

```
SELECT ip.SWOBJECTID 
FROM  MBR_INST_PRODUCTS ip JOIN
      ORO_PPY_OPTIONS po
      ON po.SWPRODRELEASEID = ip.SWPRODRELEASEID
WHERE po.SWNAME = 'Nov Flexibil Offer:Net Unlimited for 1MON') AND
      rownum = 1;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `ORO_PPY_OPTIONS(SWNAME, SWPRODRELEASEID)` and `MBR_INST_PRODUCTS(MBR_INST_PRODUCTS)`.